# What's wrong with my regex to match an integer?

Tags: c#, regex, .net-3.5

Yes, I'm sure this has been asked before on StackOverflow, but if so please point me to it, because I couldn't find it.  There are plenty of regex questions and some are even similar to what I want.

Basically, I want to match whole numbers (i.e. integers), both positive and negative.  So nothing that ends with a decimal point followed by more digits.  I only care about the English style numbering, I don't want to allow thousand separators, etc., and I only want to use a '.' as a decimal point, none of this strange 'comma is a decimal point' that some countries do.

```
^[+-]?\d+(?!\.\d)
```

But the above seems to match as follows...

```
10      matches '10'       <- yay
465654  matches '465654'   <- yay
653.56  only matches '65'  <- boo
1234.5  only matches '123' <- also boo!
```

Trying this out on [regexper](http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%5B+-%5D?%5Cd%2b%28?!%5C.%5Cd%29), visually it looks exactly like what I want.  I'm new to negative lookaheads, so I've obviously missed something here, but what is it?

Also, I should say I'm using this as part of an interpreter I'm writing, and therefore I want to allow additional content after the integer. e.g.

```
12 + some_variable
```

or (more complicatedly)...

```
10.Tostring()  <- should still match the '10'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern matches any sequence of digits not followed by a `.` and another digit. In `1234.5` the substring `123` is not followed by a `.` (because it's followed by a `4`), so it's a valid match.

Try using an end anchor (`$`) to ensure that no additional characters appear after the matched string:

```
^[+-]?\d+$
```

---

If you need to allow characters following the matched string, you might try using a negative lookahead to ensure that the matched substring is not followed by a `.` *or* a digit:

```
^[+-]?\d+(?![\d.])
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5B%2b-%5D?%5Cd%2b%28?!%5B%5Cd.%5D%29&input=10%20%20%20%20%20%20should%20matches%20%2710%27%0A465654%20%20should%20matches%20%27465654%27%0A653.56%20%20should%20not%20match%0A1234.5%20%20should%20not%20match)

---

To *also* match a string like `10.ToString()`, you could also use a negative lookahead, like this:

```
^[+-]?\d+(?!\.?\d)
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5B%2B-%5D%3F%5Cd%2B%28%3F!%5C.%3F%5Cd%29&input=10%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20should%20match%20%2710%27%0A465654%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20should%20match%20%27465654%27%0A10.ToString%28%29%20%20should%20match%20%2710%27%0A653.56%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20should%20not%20match%0A1234.5%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20should%20not%20match)

And another strategy would be to use a *positive* lookahead, like this:

```
^[+-]?\d+(?=\.\D|[^.\d]|$)
```

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%5B%2B-%5D%3F%5Cd%2B%28%3F%3D%5C.%5CD%7C%5B%5E.%5Cd%5D%7C%24%29&input=10%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20should%20match%20%2710%27%0A465654%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20should%20match%20%27465654%27%0A10.ToString%28%29%20%20should%20match%20%2710%27%0A653.56%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20should%20not%20match%0A1234.5%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20should%20not%20match)

Comment: I didn't say originally, but I don't want to match the end of the string, I want to allow for other content after my integer.

Comment: +1 and thanks, but... I would also like it to match the `10` in `10.ToString()` for example?

Comment: Many thanks mate!  Looks like I was *nearly* right then with my original...  How annoying.